# HDMI support and Nvidia Optimus systems

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, hdmi, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I see a few questions and talks of a new NVIDIA driver that allegedly supports Optimus technology, by Nvidia. I use a Dell Vostro 3500 Core i5 4GB RAM, with an Intel Video Card and a Geforce 310M GS. The systems: Ubuntu 13.04 / Win 7 (dual-boot).

My question concerns HDMI support with a video card similar to the one I have. Even with Bumblebee installed, when I had Ubuntu 12.10 running, I couldn't switch to HDMI external monitors. That's the only reason why I still use dual-boot. I would be happy even if it's possible to make HDMI working only with the Intel card.

Has anyone ever tried the new 319.12 driver by NVIDIA on Ubuntu and saw any significant difference, specially concerning HDMI support? Has anyone ever succeeded in connecting HDMI external monitors using NVIDIA drivers, with or without Bumblebee? Thanks in advance for sharing your sollutions.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded on my laptop with external HDMI : see my blog [here](http://ux51vz.blogspot.com)
I still need to figure out - at least if it's not a bug from the drivers - how to get everything working when actually NOT using HDMI because in my case it doesn't work (with nvidia drivers), but some others reported it's working.

Maybe you'll have better luck !
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

External HDMI is fully working for me on my Dell Inspirion which uses an nvidia GT 750M in optimus with the onboard intel 4000 graphics on ubuntu 15.04. I can plug and hotplug at will and can push hdmi to the limits at 3440x1440 at 30hz on my external screen.